# How to sum data based on a boolean amount?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, boolean, pandas-loc

Created dictionary called items. Combined values for different keys and put into variable food_list.

```
 items={'Food':['Ice Cream','Salad'],'Computer':['Laptop','Notebook']
 food_list= '|'.join(items['Food'])

 Description             Amount

 Lenovo Laptop           300
 Chicken Salad           40
 Dell Notebook           250
 Chocolate Ice Cream     3
```

I tried to find a string based on dictionary values. If the string is in the dictionary, then the row in the dataframe contains the string. I take the amount it is associated with and add up the total row amounts that fit the condition.

```
 total_amount=df.loc[df['Description'].str.contains(food_list,na=False)
      ==df['Amount'].sum()]
```

I usually run the code and get

```
 Empty DataFrame
 Columns: [Date, Description, Amount]
 Index: []
```

Comment: You were close, ```df.loc[df['Description'].str.contains(food_list), 'Amount'].sum()```

Comment: Thanks so much!! I think it works now. I have to check other values to make sure.